# Issues wih the Twitter API

Tags: php, api, twitter, downtime

Ok I have been signing in with **twitter** through the API using **PHP** for awhile. However today I have had nothing but issues in getting a connection!

**Has something changed with the Twitter API???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter has been having issues. Yesterday I was making twitter requests to the search and was getting 1 less result than what I asked for. with the `&count=6` I'd receive 5 and of course any other number. I woke up this morning to find I had the right number of results back.

Comment: It is about time **Twitter** got their act together if you ask me! Maybe they're finally making the move to *OAuth2** :) - You never know they could add a JavaScript SDK too!

Comment: Don't be silly! They're too busy thinking of new vague error responses to return to anyone using their API.

Comment: All I keep seeing is **Something is technically wrong** - YOU DON'T SAY! I haven't changed my code yet your API doesn't want to authorize me .... -_- google are much nicer

Comment: Two choices. Convince everyone Google+ is better... or just wait for them to fix it. Who knows infact... Maybe it's a vague response to a bad request :P

Comment: All I was doing was signing in! Basically please authorize this app on my account lol! Heres my API keys, not take me to my app .... **nope.jpg**